Correct use of Merge by Distance in Geometry Nodes, with smooth joining sites
I´d like to effectively merge two curves at their ends in Blender's Geometry Nodes without creating angles at the joining sites, while maintaining the smoothness of both curves. I wonder what is the best method to use the Merge by Distance node in this regard.

To merge two curves at their ends in Geometry Nodes smoothly without creating angles:

Align Endpoints: Make sure the endpoints of your curves are close together using the Set Position node.
Convert Curves to    Points: Use the Curve to Points node on both curves.
Merge Points: Apply the Merge by Distance node with a small distance to merge the endpoints.
Smooth the Joint: Use the Fillet Curve node with a small radius to ensure smoothness at the merge point.

These steps should help you merge curves smoothly.
